# sql_test.exe not a valid win32 application

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I'm making an application and after working all day to figure how to make a statically linked library, i finally got it but now it gives me a "Not a valid win32 application"
I read in several places that .a is for statically linked libraries and .lib is the same for windows. i only see a .a but no .lib is this the problem? I'm not really sure since it's mingw
My includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sqlite3.h> //libname exports to sqlite NOT sqlite3
#include "Database.h" //http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/122300-sqlite-in-c/
```

I'm on windows7x64 and am using mingw 4.7.2

Comment: Libraries != Executables. You need to generate an "exe" file.

Comment: the final product is an exe, but sqlite is set to compile as a library. In eclipse, my application is including the other project.

Comment: That error should only occur if the actual executable format (i.e. "exe" file generated) does not conform to the [Windows PE format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). Even if linking to a bad library, that error message should *not occur* when trying to run the executable - assuming it is a *valid* executable format. Make sure that it is targeting the correct Architecture/Executable Format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! although I'm not really sure what it means though.
Under C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> MinGW C++ Linker -> Shared Library Settings, i unchecked "Shared (-Shared)" and everything worked fine. Before it didn't work if i had the "--static" setting but now it works fine with or without it.